# Ionic Native Push Crashes using Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, ionic2, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Ionic2 and am building a Chat App with Push Messaging. I am using FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging). I followed the [following tutorial](https://medium.com/@ankushaggarwal/push-notifications-in-ionic-2-658461108c59#.abc4tad1y) which uses the [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) plugin, and everything was working perfectly.

My PC then crashed and I had to reinstall all my Cordova plugins. Since then, the Push Notifications are causing the app to crash. When I try initialise `Push` and the following code is invoked:

```
import { StatusBar, Push, SQLite } from 'ionic-native';
                    ...

            let push = Push.init({
              android: {
                senderID: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                topics: topics
              },
              ios: {
                alert: "true",
                badge: false,
                sound: "true",
                topics: topics
              },
              windows: {}
            });
```

I get the following error with nothing in the logs:

[image]

If I don't make use of Push it works with no errors, but I obviously want to use Push Notifications.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate it.

I have tried the following with no success:

1. Reinstall all Cordova Plugins
2. Created a new FCM project and used its SENDER_ID
3. Remove & Add the android platform (`ionic platform remove android` & `ionic platform add android`)
4. Tried reinstalling Ionic Native (`npm install ionic-native --save`)

More info:

> ```
> E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo>cordova plugin list
> cordova-plugin-camera 2.2.0 "Camera"
> cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
> cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
> cordova-plugin-crop 0.1.0 "CropPlugin"
> cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
> cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.2.0 "Geolocation"
> cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.0 "Network Information"
> cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
> cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
> cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
> cordova-sqlite-plugin 3.0.0 "Cordova SQLite Plugin"
> cordova-sqlite-storage 1.4.8 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
> ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
> phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.3 "PushPlugin"
> plugin.google.maps 1.3.9 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"
> ```

`npm install` gives me the following:

....

> ```
> npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
>
> > node-sass@3.10.1 postinstall E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo\node_modules\ionic-gulp-sass-build\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
> > node scripts/build.js
>
> "E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo\node_modules\ionic-gulp-sass-build\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-48\binding.node" exists.
>  testing binary.
> Binary is fine; exiting.
> npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
> npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Richard\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
> npm ERR! node v6.2.2
> npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
> npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID
>
> npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/compiler@2.1.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/forms@0.2.0 wants @angular/compiler@^2.0.0-rc.4
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.2 wants @angular/compiler@2.1.2
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ionic-angular@2.0.0-rc.1 wants @angular/compiler@^2.0.0
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-server@2.1.2 wants @angular/compiler@2.1.2
> npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 wants @angular/compiler@2.0.2
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
> npm ERR!     E:\Development\IDE\ionic-apps\theWhoZoo\npm-debug.log
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try to this way:

1. use "phonegap-plugin-push 1.8.4"
2. Don't use native "import {StatusBar, Push, SQLite } from 'ionic-native';"
3. try with import { Push, PushToken } from '@ionic/cloud-angular';  (youpage.ts)
4. import { CloudSettings, CloudModule } from '@ionic/cloud-angular'; (app.module.ts)

   ```
    const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = { 'core': {
               'app_id': 'xxx'
             },
             'push': {
               'sender_id': 'yyy',
               'pluginConfig': {
                 'ios': {
                   'badge': true,
                   'sound': true
                 },
                 'android': {
                   'iconColor': '#ff0000'
                 }
               }
             }
           };
   ```

Its working for me.